« la longue sonate des cadavres » : sens; Molloy, Samuel Beckett
Tiré de Molloy, Samuel Beckett
Partie qui précède la phrase, même paragraphe

Et cette
ville, la seule qu’il m’ait été donné de connaître, j’en cherchai le nom,
dans ma mémoire, avec l’intention, dès que je l’aurais trouvé, de
m’arrêter et de dire à un passant, tout en me découvrant, Pardon,
monsieur, c’est bien X ici, X étant le nom de ma ville. Ce nom que je
cherchais, il me semblait bien qu’il commençait par un B ou par un P,
mais malgré cet indice, ou à cause peut-être de sa fausseté, les
autres lettres continuaient à m’échapper. Il y avait si longtemps que
je vivais loin des mots, vous comprenez, qu’il me suffisait de voir ma
ville par exemple, puisqu’il s’agit ici de ma ville, pour ne pas pouvoir,
vous comprenez. C’est trop difficile à dire, pour moi. De même la
sensation de ma personne s’enveloppait d’un anonymat souvent
difficile à percer, nous venons de le voir je crois. Et ainsi de suite
pour les autres choses qui me bafouaient les sens.   Oui, même à cette époque, où tout s’estompait déjà, ondes et particules, la condition de l’objet était d’être sans nom, et inversement. Je dis ça  maintenant, mais au fond qu’en sais-je maintenant, de cette époque, maintenant que grêlent sur moi les mots glacés de sens et que le monde meurt aussi, lâchement, lourdement nommé ?

La phrase

J’en sais ce
que savent les mots et les choses mortes et ça fait une jolie petite somme, avec un commencement, un milieu et une fin, comme dans les phrases bien bâties et dans la longue sonate des cadavres.

Que doit-on lire dans cette image ? Comment l'expliquer ?

Une sonate, ou plus exactement son 1er mouvement, c'est une exposition de deux thèmes un peu comme l'énoncé d'un problème; un développement qui cherche à le résoudre: trouver une progression mélodieuse du 1er au 2ème; enfin une récapitulation qui présente une résolution du matériel thématique. Cette structure est l'allégorie de la vie humaine: lorsque le morceau est terminé, l'homme est devenu cadavre, pour qui tous les problèmes sont résolus.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(music)

@FrançoisJurain Pourquoi longue?

@Frank Ben... euh... parce que ça va mieux en le disant? Parce qu'une sonate de 70 ans doit paraître longue aux auditeurs?

@FrançoisJurain Les réponses même partielles ne sont pas des commentaires ; elles se font dans l'espace réponse.

@FrançoisJurain Je me suis dit que ce qui est long, c'est la série de tous les morts.

Je ne vois pas qu'on doive lire quoi que ce fût dans cette image. Faute de contexte, j'ignore de quoi "savent les mots et les choses mortes"; la "jolie petite somme" est un traité (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/somme sens 4).
J'imagine donc que leur science, et le sujet de ce traité, est celle de la vie; comme une phrase bien bâtie ou une sonate (plus exactement, comme le 1er mouvement d'une sonate classique), elle a un commencement, un milieu et une fin. Tout au moins, comme la sonate des cadavres: sans quoi la conclusion du mouvement, avec la résolution musicale du matériau thématique qu'elle apportait, manquera. Il n'est pas difficile de filer la métaphore ad nauseam.

Je ne pense pas que « somme » soit à rapprocher de « traité » ;  « totalité »  doit être le terme le plus approprié (« somme de mes connaissances » : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+somme+de+mes+connaissances&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3). Il n'est pas question de science, le narrateur est une sorte de vagabond qui se déplace à bicyclette.

@LPH comment? Môssieu se veut initié à la musicologie (il connaît la forme sonate), à la mécanique quantique (il a entendu parler de la dualité onde-particule) et ne peut même pas citer la Somme théologique de St Thomas d'Aquin? Fi donc. Ces bicyclistes, quels cuistres.

https://aquinas.cc/la/en/~ST.I <<< Très bon site.

@Frank Certes. Même qu'on en devrait bourrer le crâne de tous les vagabonds sénescents et bicyclés, que je dis moi.
Car.

@FrançoisJurain Certes. Pour info, je commence à voir d'un mauvais oeil l'analyse forcenée de toutes ces expressions, qui à mon avis réduit le plaisir de la lecture. On n'est pas obligé de tout disséquer, on peut se laisser emporter par les images évoquées. Pas une critique de toi en particulier, mais de la démarche de ces questions qui visent à enfermer Beckett dans une série de définitions ou d'explications plus ou moins uniques. Pas la bonne façon de lire Beckett, à mon avis.

@Frank je suppose qu'il faut de tout pour faire un lectorat de Beckett, y compris des gens fermement décidés à croire qu'il écrivait pour que ses lecteurs (à commencer par son éditeur) ne le comprennent pas. Pt^t aussi des étudiants étrangers qui n'ont pas sous la main une édition annotée dans leur langue.

@FrançoisJurain Ca dépend de ce que l'on comprend par comprendre.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

La résolution de cette question n'est pas facile sans une connaissance de ce que la sonate représente en musique, mais fort d'une bonne compréhension de cette forme musicale, les notions communiquées par un spécialiste de la littérature ne sont pas de trop pour s'assurer de l'idée que Beckett introduit.
Certaines de ces notions nous sont données par Laurent Mattiussi dans Fictions de l'ipséité: essai sur l'invention narrative de soi (Beckett, Hesse, Kafka, Musil, Proust, Woolf) 2002- p. 83, et cela semble suffire pour une explication de l'idée dans ses implications élémentaires.

Cette sonate, c'est la vie, et les cadavres sont les vivants.
Il faut comprendre ce que l'on entend par sonate en musique classique ; la Wikipédia explique ça très bien.

En musique classique, la forme « sonate » est une forme musicale qui est composée de trois parties : l'exposition, le développement et la réexposition (ou récapitulation).
La forme « sonate » est le plus souvent fondée sur deux thèmes musicaux, utilisés lors de l'exposition et la réexposition, et souvent combinés ou se répondant lors du développement.

À partir de ces informations on assimile la vie de l'être humain à  une sonate, avec l'exposition comme entrée dans la vie, pendant le jeune âge, le développement comme période de l'âge mûr, et la réexposition comme la période du déclin vers la mort, cette période étant reconnue pour son caractère en partie analogue au jeune âge (ce qui correspond à la similarité entre la
première et la seconde partie de cette forme musicale).

Il semble difficile d'expliquer cette citation sans parler des rapports de Beckett à la musique, rapport qu'il expose à sa lettre à Axel Kaun (1937). Je viens d'en trouver un extrait dans un article en ligne Je pense réfèrerais aussi au  Les silences de Molloy de Georges Bataille. Enfin les universitaire ont beaucoup écrit sur le sujet.

On peut rentrer dans le détail et sentez-vous libre de le faire dans une réponse, mais ce qui importe tout d'abord c'est la question élémentaire, ses simples éléments, pour la nécessité d'une lecture passablement bien informée.
